# Parallel programming on a Quad-Core and a VM?

Tags: virtualization, parallel-processing, openmpi

I'm thinking of slowly picking up Parallel Programming. I've seen people use clusters with OpenMPI installed to learn this stuff. I do not have access to a cluster but have a Quad-Core machine. Will I be able to experience any benefit here? Also, if I'm running linux inside a Virtual machine, does it make sense in using OpenMPI inside a VM?

Comment: Is your code computation bound or IO bound? How many CPUs does the VM see?

Comment: About the computation bound or IO bound, I am open to both. I'm just starting in this area. About the cpu's, I assigned all the 4 cores to VM...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your target is to learn, you don't need a cluster at all. Your quad-core (or any dual-core or even a single-cored) computer will be more than enough. The main point is to learn how to think "in parallel" and how to design your application.

Some important points are to:

- Exploit different parallelism paradigms like divide-and-conquer, master-worker, SPMD, ... depending on data and tasks dependencies of what you want to do.
- Chose different data division granularities to check the computation/communication ratio (in case of message passing), or to check the amount of serial execution because of mutual exclusion to memory regions.

Having a quad-core you can measure your approach speedup (the gain on performance attained because of the parallelization) which is normally given by the division between the time of the non parallelized execution and the time of the parallel execution. 
The closer you get to 4 (four cores meaning 1/4th the execution time), the better your parallelization strategy was (once you could evenly distribute work and data).

Comment: Great... Thank you.. You pretty much covered everything I was looking for.